# Winium remote automation?

Tags: selenium, remote-desktop

I am using Winium to automate a desktop application. The process is I download a file from the web and execute it. which opens the remote application. Till here everything is working fine, but I am unable to access any control of that newly launched remote Citrix application. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public void SetupEnv() throws InterruptedException
{
    DesktopOptions options = new DesktopOptions();
    options.setApplicationPath("C:\\Users\\ajinkya\\Downloads\\launch.ica");

    try
    {
        driver = new WiniumDriver(new URL("http://localhost:9999"), options);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElementByClassName("Transparent Windows Client").click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: I am using Winium automation framework

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try something like this:

```
WebElement window =  driver.findElementByName("abcd.exe");
WebElement menuItem = window.findElement(By.name ("Find Item"));
menuItem.click();
```